# Shortcut to collapse all documentation headers/comments in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to collapse all documentation headers (/// comments) in the current file in visual studio (2008+)?

Comment: I [suggested a feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579/suggestions/16950865) that would make this easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, but that will collapse function bodies as well.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but nice to know. What is the expand all shortcut now that I've collapsed everything in my file? :)

Comment: @Veli: All the stuff you need is available from the Edit menu's Outlining submenu. Ctrl M M collapes / expands the currently active block, be it a comment, class or metod etc.

Answer (score 3):

What Anton said.

If what you want is not on Edit|Outlining, you'd need to write a macro or a DxCore plugin to walk it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> each relevant block.

Comment: yeah I figured that might be the case, I'm too lazy to collapse each one individually, let along write a plugin/macro... though would be a fun exercise if I ever get some free time :)

Comment: @Veli: It is actually a very easy thing to do with DXCore, and there are lots of examples that do very similar traversals of a code tree. Or you could record a temporary macro that does a repeated find of `///` and a `Ctrl M M`. (Yes, I understand you were looking for something OOTB and if someone started stating the obvious like this at me I'd tell them where to go right now!)