# Collapse summary by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there an option so Visual Studio Professional 2017 would collapse all summarys by default? Or at least a kaybind for that. I couldn't find anything on the internet or in the options. Some plugin would also be an acceptable answer

Macros don't work since they were removed from Visual Studio in previous versions.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117352/618441?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have Visual Studio collapse summary sections by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954434/is-it-possible-to-have-visual-studio-collapse-summary-sections-by-default)

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen Thanks, I must have missed it, because I only searched for "summary" keyword, not "xml documentation". This looks like exactly what I want, but I will know only after I learned how to create a macro (also in your link, awesome!).

In the meantime, you can add this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut to collapse all documentation headers/comments in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116685/shortcut-to-collapse-all-documentation-headers-comments-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @WojtekPojda Just flagged as duplicate so people are redirected to the other answer :-).

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen Ok, now I have a different problem. The guide you linked is quite outdated and from what I found Microsoft removed creating macros in Visual Studio thus making this solution impossible to use. Any solution for that?

Comment: @WojtekPojda Hmm. That is problematic! :-). I gave the extension catalog a quick search and found this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.HideShowComments

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen Awesome, thanks a lot! Turns out I really can't search. I will just throw here a link to newer version of the extension you linked as I needed it to work with VS2017: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment#overview